# Debug LLVM pass seg fault

Tags: c++, llvm

I am writing a toy compiler based on the [tutorial on the LLVM site](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl1.html), but I am now getting an error during the code generation (I believe). Program crashed with a seg fault, in the `llvm::TypeFinder::incorporateValue` method, and I can't figure out what is happening.

This is the output from LLDB when the crash happens.

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x2dfc, 0x0000000000a2a2d0 wtf`llvm::TypeFinder::incorporateValue(llvm::Value const*) + 16, stop reason = invalid address
    frame #0: 0x0000000000a2a2d0 wtf`llvm::TypeFinder::incorporateValue(llvm::Value const*) + 16
wtf`llvm::TypeFinder::incorporateValue(llvm::Value const*) + 16:
-> 0xa2a2d0:  movb   8(%r14), %al
   0xa2a2d4:  cmpb   $17, %al
   0xa2a2d6:  jne    0xa2a332                  ; llvm::TypeFinder::incorporateValue(llvm::Value const*) + 114
   0xa2a2d8:  movq   %r14, (%rsp)
```

It occurs when I try to dump the IR code of the function, when `verifyFunction` is run on it or when the `FunctionPassManager` tries to optimize it. When the FPM runs it fails with

```
Stack dump:
0.  Running pass 'Module Verifier' on function '@foo'
[1]    11485 segmentation fault (core dumped)  bin/wtf examples/simple.wtf
```

And this is the code that generates the error

```
Function *Codegen::Generate(FunctionAST *funcAst) {
  NamedValues.clear();

  Function *func = this->Generate(funcAst->GetPrototype());
  if (func == 0)
    return 0;

  BasicBlock *block = BasicBlock::Create(getGlobalContext(), "entry", func);
  Builder.SetInsertPoint(block);

  // iterate and codegen all expressions in body  
  Value *retVal = this->Generate(funcAst->GetBody());

  if (retVal) {
    Builder.CreateRet(retVal);
    verifyFunction(*func);
    TheFPM->run(*func); // <----- crash happens here
    return func;
  }

  func->eraseFromParent();

  return 0;
};
```

**I am looking for either the reason for the crash or just some way to narrow it down**, since stepping through with LLDB does not help me much (probably because I don't understand the internals of LLVM)

This is a backtrace when LLDB fails on `verifyFunction`:

```
frame #0: 0x0000000000a2a225 wtf`llvm::TypeFinder::incorporateType(llvm::Type*) + 53
frame #1: 0x0000000000a29e1b wtf`llvm::TypeFinder::run(llvm::Module const&, bool) + 91
frame #2: 0x000000000098d91b wtf`(anonymous namespace)::TypePrinting::incorporateTypes(llvm::Module const&) + 27
frame #3: 0x00000000009907f5 wtf`llvm::Value::print(llvm::raw_ostream&, llvm::AssemblyAnnotationWriter*) const + 2421
frame #4: 0x0000000000a316cf wtf`(anonymous namespace)::Verifier::CheckFailed(llvm::Twine const&, llvm::Value const*, llvm::Type*, llvm::Value const*) + 143
frame #5: 0x0000000000a30ca5 wtf`(anonymous namespace)::Verifier::visitFunction(llvm::Function&) + 421
frame #6: 0x0000000000a2fd84 wtf`(anonymous namespace)::Verifier::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) + 132
frame #7: 0x0000000000a1d99e wtf`llvm::FPPassManager::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) + 318
frame #8: 0x0000000000a1d243 wtf`llvm::FunctionPassManagerImpl::run(llvm::Function&) + 195
frame #9: 0x0000000000a1d11d wtf`llvm::FunctionPassManager::run(llvm::Function&) + 93
frame #10: 0x0000000000a2f98a wtf`llvm::verifyFunction(llvm::Function const&, llvm::VerifierFailureAction) + 538
frame #11: 0x00000000004cef02 wtf`Codegen::Generate(this=<unavailable>, funcAst=<unavailable>) + 226 at Codegen.cpp:325
frame #12: 0x00000000004da96b wtf`Driver::Go(std::string) [inlined] Driver::HandleDefinition(this=<unavailable>) + 27 at Driver.cpp:5
frame #13: 0x00000000004da950 wtf`Driver::Go(this=<unavailable>, file=<unavailable>) + 208 at Driver.cpp:61
frame #14: 0x00000000004db71c wtf`main(argc=<unavailable>, argv=<unavailable>) + 364 at main.cpp:30
frame #15: 0x00007ff648bb476d libc.so.6`__libc_start_main + 237
frame #16: 0x00000000004cb9bd wtf`_start + 41
```

Comment: Pointing at the `PassManager::run` invocation doesn't say much because the crash is inside of the passes this PM runs. From what you're describing, you have malformed IR somewhere. You say it segfaults during module dumping. Does it manage to dump anything before segfaulting? Perhaps by looking at the exact segfault location you can figure out which instruction is malformed.

Comment: I believe that the place it segfaults is in the `TypeFinder::incorporateValue` function, at the instruction `movb   8(%r14), %al`, but I am not proficient enough to deduce anything from that. And no, nothing is dumped unfortunately.

Comment: Climb higher in the frame stack to see which pass crashes and where in the pass. The frame you're focusing on is too low-level to deduce anything useful.

Comment: Just edited that in. But now I realized two odd things:
 (1.)  When the execution reaches `if (retVal) { ...` it suddenly jumps two lines back and continues as usual. As is multiple threads are working (there are not).
 (2.)  It seems there is something fundamentally wrong with the code. When I try to inspect `func` in the above snippet, this is what LLDB tells me.
`(lldb) p *func` gives
`error: Couldn't materialize struct: size of variable func disagrees with the ValueObject's size`

Comment: In frame #4 you have a "check failed" invocation of the verified. Probably something wrong with the IR there.

Comment: I can't seem to get anything useful out of this. I am now compiling with no optimizations, so now there are no weird jumps. I can print `func`, but when I try to dump it, I get `error: Execution was interrupted, reason: invalid address.`, which again does not help me much...

Comment: I fear there's no simple solution to this. Just good old roll-up-your-sleeves debugging. Try to reproduce the smallest code that gives the failure and then track the IR through all the steps your code is making to see where things go awry.

Comment: It turned out to be an error that would make no sense to explain here, as it is unrelated to the question asked. Thanks a lot Eli for helping out!